# SQL Multiple update record from SELECT WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help.

I want to totally quantity of material with the same id in any bill.

like this

```
bill no. 001
jellopy x1ea
jellopy x1ea
jellopy x1ea
zargon x1ea
```

result should be

```
bill no. 001
jellopy x3ea
zargon x1ea
```

So,I want to do something like this

1.select+sum 2.update 3.delete duplicate

here is my old (dbill) table

**dbill**

```
id  mat  qty
01  A1   1
01  A1   1
01  A1   1
01  A2   1

id  mat  qty
[01  A1   1] < same mat&id = SUM it
[01  A1   1] < same mat&id = SUM it
[01  A1   1] < same mat&id = SUM it
 01  A2   1
```

> and this is SQLFiddle for test http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b30a3c

[1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b30a3c) SUM quantity with the same material

```
SELECT mat,id,sum(qty) result
FROM dbill
GROUP BY id,mat
```

[2] got result like this

```
id  mat  qty
01  A1   3
01  A2   1
```

[3] so... i will update like this

```
UPDATE dbill
SET qty = result
FROM dbill t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT mat,id,sum(qty) result
FROM dbill
GROUP BY id,mat) s
ON s.id = t.id
AND s.mat = t.mat
```

the problem is when i [3] UPDATE here is the result

```
id  mat  qty
01  A1   3
01  A1   3
01  A1   3
01  A2   3
```

because the correct result should be

```
id  mat  qty
01  A1   3
01  A1   3
01  A1   3
01  A2   1     <
```

Thank you very much for you understand and answer ...

Comment: [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list*"

Answer (score 1):

For me your query seems to be ok just replace `UPDATE dbill` with `UPDATE t`

```
UPDATE t <----
SET qty = result
FROM dbill t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT mat,id,sum(qty) result
 FROM dbill
 GROUP BY id,mat) s
ON s.id = t.id
AND s.mat = t.mat
```

Comment: IMHO this is Microsoft syntax.

Comment: same result for me, i thought, anyway, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe less elegant but should work

```
  UPDATE dbill t
  SET t.qty = (select sum(qty) from dbill t2 where t2.id=t.id and t2.mat=t.mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !!!

Here, This is my solution.